# Is there a way to enforce Generic Constraints based on type rather than duck typing?

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript2.0

The `Tester.test()` method will compile and run successfully even though `SomeQuery1` implements `IQueryWithResponse<SomeResponse1>` and not `iQueryWithResponse<SomeResponse2>`

```
export interface IQueryWithResponse<TResponse> {
}

export class SomeQuery1 implements IQueryWithResponse<SomeResponse1> {
}
export class SomeResponse1 {
}

export class SomeQuery2 implements IQueryWithResponse<SomeResponse2> {
}
export class SomeResponse2 {
}

export class Tester {
  public doRequest<TRequest extends IQueryWithResponse<TResponse>, TResponse>(request: TRequest) : TResponse {
    return null;
  }

  public test() {
    let query = new SomeQuery1();
    let response = this.doRequest<SomeQuery1, SomeResponse2>(query);
  }
}
```

If this were a language like C# the compiler would throw an error due to the constraint on `Tester.doRequest()`, but in TypeScript I can pass any type for `TResponse` as long as it implements the same members as the type I am expecting (which in this example is absolutely anything).

I would like to be able to enforce this generic constraint checking at compile time. Or, at the very least, have a way of ensuring in `Tester.doRequest` at runtime that `request` implements `IQueryWithResponse<TResponse>`

Perhaps there is a way to solve this using meta-data?

Comment: In runtime you can check the value you are getting and decide if it fits, if not throw an error. You can check this issue: [Support some non-structural (nominal) type matching](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202) for how you can workaround the duck typing nature of typescript

Comment: See also https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way I know of is to have some constant value that differentiates the interfaces. Its technically the same "type" (string) but typescript allows you to be specific about its expected value(s) and will complain if the constant doesn't match.

[image]

Its a solution; can't say I like it. :P

Comment: Thanks. I don't think this will work though as there is only a single interface that is generic. Here is a working example....that I wish wouldn't work :) Look on tinyurl.com using /k2jod7a